# IllegalStateException with TelephonyProvider

Tags: java, android, sms

I use Easy Content Providers from [here](https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers)

In my build.gradle:

```
compile 'me.everything:providers-android:1.0.1'
```

I want to get all SMS threads.
I use this code (from [here](https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers/wiki/Android-providers)):

```
public void smsOnClick (View view){
   TelephonyProvider telephonyProvider = new TelephonyProvider(this);
   List<Thread> threads = telephonyProvider.getThreads().getList();
}
```

But although I have the same code as in the wiki, I get this exeption:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.daandtu.chat, PID: 3420
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4054)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4809)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20123)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4049)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4809) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20123) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750) 
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
                                                                      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
                                                                      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:420)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:490)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
                                                                      at me.everything.providers.core.AbstractProvider.getContentTableData(AbstractProvider.java:29)
                                                                      at me.everything.providers.android.telephony.TelephonyProvider.getThreads(TelephonyProvider.java:98)
                                                                      at com.daandtu.chatexport.MainActivity.smsOnClick(MainActivity.java:145)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4049) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4809) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20123) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

So what is wrong with my code?
Thanks for help

Comment: show us your `onClick()`

Comment: You're trying to call `.equals()` on a null object. Show some more code.

Comment: The exeption says the error is in the last line (`telephonyProvider.getThreads()`). But where is there `.equals()`?

Comment: also can you tell which version of android are you running this?

Comment: Android 5.0 @SripadRaj